# excel - Change define name dynamically through VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

The question is if the vlookup in line 23 works why doesn't the value pass into the nested vlookup in line 26/27?  How do I get the nested vlookup to get the value **table1** with out using an if statement?

Not sure how I can share the excel workbook, if anyone knows please post in the comments.

[image]

```
# Defined Tables            
table1      table2  
Bob A   Tim C
Jim B   Karl    D
        
# Defined Name          
tables (defined name)           
1   table1  Sheet1!$A$3:$B$4    
2   table2  Sheet1!$C$3:$D$4    
        
# Table Setting             
Table Setting   1   table1  <IF(B12=1,B8,B9)
        
# Works manual with table1/2 text entered           
Bob A   <VLOOKUP(A15,table1,2,FALSE)    
Tim C   <VLOOKUP(A16,table2,2,FALSE)    
        
# Works based on changing the table settings            
Bob A   <VLOOKUP(A19,IF(B12=1,table1,IF(B12=2,table2,"ERR")),2,FALSE)   
Tim #N/A    <VLOOKUP(A20,IF(B12=1,table1,IF(B12=2,table2,"ERR")),2,FALSE)   
        
# DOESN"T WORK          
    table1  <VLOOKUP(B12,A8:B9,2,FALSE) 
        
# Although it does get the name the formula below doesn't seem to be using the name like the if condition did           
Bob #VALUE! <VLOOKUP(A25,VLOOKUP(B12,A8:B9,2,FALSE),2,FALSE)    
Tim #VALUE! <VLOOKUP(A26,VLOOKUP(B12,A8:B9,2,FALSE),2,FALSE)
```

Comment: You try to lookup the second column of a single value. You need to use INDIRECT, but as you're already using VBA, search for a VBA solution avoiding volatile function INDIRECT.

Comment: I see it's not code, but data/text. Try `=VLOOKUP(A25,INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(B12,A8:B9,2,FALSE)),2,FALSE)`. Please be aware that INDIRECT makes the formula volatile (recalculates in each change in the file) so it's likely to slow things down.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already, you can use `INDIRECT` to refernce the named range from the name of the named range.  That has the disadvantage of being volitile

```
=VLOOKUP(A26,INDIRECT(VLOOKUP($B$12,$A$8:$B$9,2,FALSE)),2,FALSE)
```

Alternatively, if you define a Named Range (say, `tables`) as a non-contiguous set of table ranges (That would be `=table1,table2` for your sample data) you can use `INDEX` to get the table by number, by providing the [area_num] parameter.

Name definition
[image]

Formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A25,INDEX(tables,,,$B$12),2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Demo
[image]